# Writing JSON to file - wrong format?

Tags: python, json

In `Python`, I'm trying to take an `XML` file, process it, then output the data to a `JSON`.  The XML processing works fine, but I am having trouble properly formatting the JSON.  The output file looks more like a list with dictionaries inside of it, which makes sense because that's what the code actually does.  How can I make this a proper JSON file?

```
filename = 'data.json'

d = []

for elem in ET.fromstring(data).findall('.//table/row'):
        field1 = elem.get('field1')
        field2 = elem.get('field2')
        field3 = elem.get('field3')
        field4 = elem.get('field4')
        l = {'field1' : field1, 
             'field2' : field2, 
             'field3' : field3, 
             'field4' : field4}
        d.append(l)

f_out = open(filename, 'w')
json.dump(d, f_out)

f_out.close()
```

The output file looks like this:

```
[{"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "field3": "field3", "field4": "field4"}, ... {"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "field3": "field3", "field4": "field4"}]
```

When I would expect it to look like:

```
{"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "field3": "field3", "field4": "field4"}, ... {"field1": "field1", "field2": "field2", "field3": "field3", "field4": "field4"}
```

Comment: when you json.dump try adding indent

Comment: Your code looks fine. I suspect that the output is a "proper JSON file". Please show the output you get from this program, and what output you expected.

Comment: You're writing `d`, which is a list, which is expressed in JSON as `[item1, item2, item3]`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Maybe that's a better question - if I need to output properly formatted JSON, what's the appropriate way to implement that?

Comment: The file you're writing is correct JSON.  Is something else (another program, perhaps) telling you it's wrong?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes - trying to copy into a database.  The error is "Invalid JSONPath format: Member is not an object.".  The error is occurring at the "[" character in the first position.  I believe the database is expecting "{" and not "[{"

Comment: Your actual output (except for the ellipsis) is valid JSON. Your expected output is not valid JSON. A JSON file cannot be a sequence of objects, but can be a list of objects.

Comment: Are you using AWS Redshift?

Comment: How are you entering the JSON into the database?  Does your database have some mechanism for importing directly from the file, or are you using an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @Robᵩ it is redshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-copy-from-json), the Redshift COPY command expects a sequence of JSON objects in its input file, and a sequence of JSON objects in its optional JSONPath file.

To create such a sequence, call `json.dump()` multiple times:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import json


data = '''
<root><table>
  <row field1="a" field2="b" field3="c" field4="d"/>
  <row field1="1" field2="2" field3="3" field4="4"/>
</table></root>'''

filename = 'data.json'
f_out = open(filename, 'w')
for elem in ET.fromstring(data).findall('.//table/row'):
        field1 = elem.get('field1')
        field2 = elem.get('field2')
        field3 = elem.get('field3')
        field4 = elem.get('field4')
        l = {'field1' : field1,
             'field2' : field2,
             'field3' : field3,
             'field4' : field4}
        json.dump(l, f_out)
        f_out.write('\n')

f_out.close()
```

Result:

```
{"field2": "b", "field3": "c", "field1": "a", "field4": "d"}
{"field2": "2", "field3": "3", "field1": "1", "field4": "4"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.dump()` has an indent and a separators parameter which you might want to supply if your json file should be human-readable.

Example:

```
json.dump({'1': 2, '3': 4}, f_out, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Result:

```
{
    "1": 2,
    "3": 4
}
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage